# Overridden my desktop with mount

Tags: mount

I tried to mount a shared folder called 'shared' like this:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf shared /home/MyUser/Desktop
```

I thought that would mount the shared folder into my desktop, not my desktop.

Is there a way to retrieve my files?

*edit* I had files on my desktop and after the mount they were gone.Is there a way to get them back?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything to "retrieve" you files - beyond unmounting the share from over the top of them

Comment: I currently have 'Desktop' and another test.txt file that was inside the shared folder on my desktop, would unmounting 'Desktop' work?
can you please tell me the exact command i should do?

Comment: «into my desktop, not my desktop» This is likely a typo. :D

Answer (score 4):

Do `sudo umount /home/Desktop` to undo what you did (or wherever you mounted it, I believe you probably meant `/home/<yourusername>/Desktop`).

Do `mkdir ~/Desktop/SharedFolder` then `sudo mount -t vboxsf shared ~/Desktop/SharedFolder` to mount it.

Comment: that just deleted the mounted 'Desktop' 
all of my previous files that were on my desktop before the mount still missing

Comment: Maybe you need to refresh the view?